# Javascript for-in loop issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

I'm doing codecademy right now and I'm having an issue with one lesson involving for-in loops. The requirement for thi exercise is to log "bill" and "steve to the console. However, I'm getting the entire array except those two strings logged instead. What's going on here?

```
   var friends = {
    bill: {firstName: "Bill", 
            lastName: "Ferny",
            number: "452-556-5412", 
            address: ['One Bree Hill', 'Bree', 'Middle Earth', '00000']
           },
    steve: {firstName:"Steve",
             lastName:"Rogers",
             number:"805-223-5568",
             address: ['1500 Settlers Court', 'Paso Robles', 'CA', '93446']
             }
   };
   var list = function (friends) {
       for (var p in friends) {
    console.log(friends[p]);
    }
   };
   list(friends);
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what output you're seeing, could you add what you're getting.

Comment: You're logging the values, not the keys.

Comment: `friends[p]` points to the object `{...}`, hint: you want a *property* of that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `for-in` loop, the variable is set to the property names. So if you want to log the property name, use `console.log(p)`. `friends[p]` is the value that the property name maps to in the object.

Answer (score 2):

change `console.log(friends[p]);` into `console.log(friends[p].firstName);`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you want even further.

This:

```
console.log(friends[p]);
```

should be changed to this:

```
console.log(friends[p].firstName);
```

Your code is only getting you all of the properties associated with `friends[bill]` and `friends[steve]`. You want their first names, so you have to use dot notation and add `.firstName` to the end of your `console.log()` statements.

As other people have noted, you can also use `console.log(p)` which logs the property name (so bill and steve), but since you are on Codecademy, I think they'll want you to use the first method I mentioned.